# Не могу пристроить декоратор

Tags: python, декоратор

Задача заключается в том чтобы декоратор вывел имя функции и результат её выполнения.

```
@debug
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
    
add(3,4)
```

Ожидаемый вывод:

```
add(3, 4) was called and returned 7.
```

Comment: сам декоратор-то где?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Пример:***

```py
def debug(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        result = repr(f(*args, **kwargs))

        args = ', '.join(repr(arg) for arg in args)
        kwargs = ', '.join(f'{k}={repr(kwargs[k])}' for k in kwargs)
        all_args = f'{args}, {kwargs}' if kwargs else args
        print(f'{f.__name__}({all_args}) was called and returned {result}.')

        return result
    return wrapped


@debug
def add(a, b):
    return a + b


add(3, 4)
```

***stdout:***

```py
add(3, 4) was called and returned 7.
```

Comment: Спасибо, огромное.